# How do I find the value of each Switch Case Item in C# or Java?

Tags: java, c#, switch-statement, case

Say for instance I have this:

```
string myString = "hello";

switch (myString) {
case "hello":
break;
case "goodbye":
break;
}
```

Now I want a method or piece of code, that will retrieve the value of each case declared.

For example, I want to output "hello" and "goodbye" is there a way to get these values?

I was looking for something like this (HYPOTHETICAL):

```
foreach (case in switch(myString)){
System.out.println("")
}
```

//which I want output to look like this:

```
System.out.println("hello")
System.out.println("goodbye")
```

as a result of the foreach loop. Is something like this possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Inspecting your own source code is a very unusual pattern. What problem are you trying to solve here? You're probably better off using a list or dictionary to hold your "cases" and iterating over it instead of using a switch/case.

Comment: Analyzing your own code can't be done without "Reflection", which is more difficult and slow. Using an enum/dictionary to the hold the values would be better.

Answer (score 2):

In C# (the answer for Java could be quite different…IMHO it's bad form to have used both tags):

There is no practical way to do what you want. You'd have to reimplement something like dotPeek's or Reflector's functionality, getting the IL for the method and decompiling it to recover the `switch` statement cases.

However, note that a `switch` statement can be implemented as a dictionary-based dispatch of delegates. If you do that, then you can just enumerate the keys of your dictionary.

For example:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> switchStatement = new Dictionary<string, Action>
{
    { "hello", (Action)MyHelloAction },
    { "goodbye", (Action)MyGoodbyeAction },
};

void MyHelloAction() { /* ... */ }
void MyGoodbyeAction() { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can simply do something like:

```
foreach (string switchCase in switchStatement.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(switchCase);
}
```

Actually using the `switchStatement` would look like:

```
string myString = "hello";

switchStatement[myString]();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, there are 2 reasonably easy solutions to the problem , both using Dictionary-based dispatching. The first is to use a delegate (see Peter Duniho's answer for details). The second would be:

```
interface Dispatcher
{
    void Action();
}

class HelloDispatcher:Dispatcher
{
    internal void Action()
    {
        //place code here
    }
}

class GoodbyDispatcher:Dispatcher
{
    internal void Action()
    {
        //place code here
    }
}
```

Then, use Dictionary<string, Dispatcher> type to hold the commands.

In Java, you can only use the second solution; I believe you would want a TreeMap there, although I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it without much effort.

First of all, remove the break statement in all cases.
Second Print all case values inside all cases. Your code must be looking like.

```
public function print(String text){
System.out.println(text);
}

switch (myString) 
{
case "hello":
print("hello");

case "goodbye":
print("goodbye");

}
```